# phase portraits of automorphic functions (a la Indra's Pearls)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, automorphic-forms

I would like to make movies of phase portraits of automorphic/kleinian functions with varying traces -- On page 375 of Indra's Pearls there is a phase portrait of an automorphic function/fonction kleinneene. It says on the previous page that the function is a ratio 
$$
\left(\sum \frac{az+b}{(cz+d)^{3}}\right)\Big/\left(\sum\frac{1}{(cz+d)^{4}}\right)
$$

I'm not entirely clear what the book means by this expression.

- How do I go from the traces $t_{a}, t_{b}$ in chapter 8 -- Grandma's recipe (page 261) -- to $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ in the above expression?
- What should the above expression read? It's not clear what the index of summation is as written

Comment: It is $$F(z) = \frac{\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \frac{d}{dz}\gamma(z)^2}{\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} (\frac{d}{dz}\gamma(z))^2}$$ which is  modular of weight $-2$